# Is the GPS transmitters transfers any device specific Numbers

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services, gps

I am developing a TRACKING web application in asp.net . I am done almost with the front end . I have to clear my doubt about can i use webservices or windows services to listen on particular TCP port to receive the GPS data . and also should i have to assign different port numbers for different devices to receive , if no then how could i identify which device sends which data . According to NMEA there is no specification in the syntax . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shoud not use the Nmea protocoll to communicate from a device to a server. create your own location message, which contains the data you need. there you can include a device id in the header of your custom message.
if you are insisting on NMEA then you can create custom NMEA messages where you can add the device id.
The gps chips itself dont have a serial id, and therefore there is no NMEA message from them. So you have to use another id, e.g id of cell phone.